# Prove that $A¯ ⊆ B$ if and only if $A ∪ B = Ω$, where $Ω$ is the universal set and $A $ and $B$ are subsets of it.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am halfway done this question and I'm stuck on the second part. I split this biconditional proof into two conditional proofs.

> a) $(A¯ ⊆ B) \Rightarrow (A ∪ B = Ω) $

Direct Proof: Assume $(A¯ ⊆ B)$.
              Using the identity law, we see that $(A ∪ A¯ = Ω)$. Since $(A¯ ⊆ B)$,
              we can write that $(A ∪ B = Ω)$ because $(A ∪ B)$ will include 
              everything that $(A ∪ A¯)$ does.

> b) $(A ∪ B = Ω) \Rightarrow (A¯ ⊆ B)$

**This is where I am stuck, it feels weird having the conditional flipped because the assumption on the left side does not seem to give me clues. It just seems like an obviously true statement. I mean if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of U as the question already stated, then obviously the union of $A$ and $B$ are also a subset.

If you could solve the second portion of this problem, or give me hints (maybe what set laws to use) I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you take any $a \in \Omega$ you have to look at one case. Since $A \cup A^C=\Omega$ take an $a \in A^C$. You know $a \notin A $ and $ A \cup B = \Omega \rightarrow a\in B$. Therefore $A^C\subset B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm going to use $A^c$ to represent the complement of $A$ in $\Omega$.)

Typically when proving $X \subseteq Y$, if you can't find an elegant way to prove it with known identities (as you did in the first direction), then you can always fall back on the good old-fashioned arguments of the form "If $x \in X$ then ... (logic, logic, logic) ... therefore $x \in Y$.

So, taking this approach, we are trying to show that $A^c \subseteq B$, under the assumption that $A \cup B = \Omega$. This means, we are allowed to assume that any element of $\Omega$ must either be in $A$ or $B$ (or both).

Suppose $x \in A^c$. By definition, $x$ is not an element of $A$. But, as pointed out above, $x$ must be an element of $A$ or $B$, therefore $x \in B$. This is a proof that $A^c \subseteq B$; we're done.

Elementary set problems are usually not too hard if you break the proof down like this.